# How to make different type of arrowheads using FancyArrowPatch?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make these following arrowheads using `FancyArrowPatch` in matplotlib:

[image]

The code for producing the above plot is(taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43378730/how-to-get-an-open-and-scaling-arrow-head-in-matplotlib)):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))

v = [-0.2, 0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1]
for i, overhang in enumerate(v):
    ax.arrow(.1,overhang,.6,0, width=0.001, color="k", 
             head_width=0.1, head_length=0.15, overhang=overhang)

ax.set_yticks(v)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_ylabel("overhang")
ax.set_ylim(-0.3,1.1)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The above code uses `ax.arrow`. How can I implement this in `FancyArrowPatch`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps to experiment with `FancyArrowPatch`, `ArrowStyle`:

```
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch, ArrowStyle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
style = ArrowStyle('Fancy', head_length=1, head_width=1.5, tail_width=0.5)
arrow = FancyArrowPatch((0, 0), (1, 1), mutation_scale=25, arrowstyle=style, color='k')                     
ax.add_patch(arrow)

plt.xlim(-0.1, 1.1)
plt.ylim(-0.1, 1.1)
```

Now various parameters can be adjusted to obtain the desired result if necessary (e.g. `head_width`, `head_length`, `mutation_scale`,...)

This snippet reproduces the given plot using `matplotlib.patches.FancyArrow`:

```
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
v = [-0.2, 0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1]
for i, overhang in enumerate(v):
    arrow = FancyArrow(0, overhang, 1, 0, width = 0.001, head_width=0.1, head_length = None, color = 'k', overhang = overhang)
    ax.add_patch(arrow)

ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks(v)
ax.set_ylim(-0.3,1.1)
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, 2)
ax.set_ylabel("overhang")
```