# How to make annotation arrows that are NOT xkcd stylized

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib version 3.7.1 and it appears that the default annotation arrows are stylized following [xkcd](https://www.xkcd.com).  Here is a simple plot demonstrating this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6, 6))

p1 = 0.3
p2 = 0.7
ax.axvline(p1, color='k', linestyle='solid')
ax.axvline(p2, color='k', linestyle='solid')
ax.annotate('blah', xy=(p1, 0.75), xytext=(p2, 0.75), 
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<->')
           )

ax.set_ylim(0, 1.1)
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
plt.show()
```

[image: wiggly arrow lines]

Notice that the line is neither straight nor level and the arrow heads do not span the entire distance.  Notice as well that I did not enable this feature, it appears to be the default.  The [matplotlib annotation gallery](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/fancyarrow_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-fancyarrow-demo-py) makes it seem like this is the expected outcome.  I would like to turn all this off and get straight lines.

Edit: In response to a comment that says the line is straight, here is the code to plot level, straight arrows to/from the same points (in red):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6, 6))

p1 = 0.3
p2 = 0.7
ax.axvline(p1, color='k', linestyle='solid')
ax.axvline(p2, color='k', linestyle='solid')

ax.arrow(p1, 0.75, p2 - p1, 0, length_includes_head=True, 
         head_width=0.1, head_length=0.01, facecolor='none', 
         overhang=1, edgecolor='r', alpha=0.5)
ax.arrow(p2, 0.75, p1 - p2, 0, length_includes_head=True, 
         head_width=0.1, head_length=0.01, facecolor='none', 
         overhang=1, edgecolor='r', alpha=0.5)

ax.annotate('blah', xy=(p1, 0.75), xytext=(p2, 0.75), 
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<->')
           )

ax.set_ylim(0, 1.1)
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
plt.show()
```

[image: xkcd line with level line]

The annotation line is clearly neither straight (it wiggles) nor level.  At any rate, that maybe this is functioning as intended is beside the point, the question to be answered is how do I get straight, level lines using annotate.

Comment: This answer to a slightly different question will work with overhang=1 and using normal arrows, but I'd like to use annotate if I can.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43379608/6024187

Comment: The connections in the annotation arrow style reference are curved because they explicitly curved the connections with `connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.05"`. Yours are straight, which is the default. The alignment just isn't working the way you wanted.

Comment: Annotation arrows aren't supposed to start at `xy` and end at `xytext`. Those locations are the point you're annotating and the location you want to put the annotation text. Having the arrows go from `xy` to `xytext` would obscure the annotated point and cause readability issues for the text. (The fact that the connection isn't level is a bit awkward, though.)

Comment: Hypotesys: the connection isn't level because the line goes from the exact position of the zero-text on the left, to the vertical centre of the text on the right.

Comment: "The annotation line is clearly neither straight (it wiggles)" - no it doesn't. Try zooming in - it might be easier to see that way.

Comment: The line may not be level, but it *is* straight.

Comment: @FinncentPrice Does my answer clarify things? If so, you can consider accepting it.

Comment: @jared I will not accept your answer because your first sentence claims that the line in the original plots is straight.  As that is clearly not true, I cannot accept your answer because it is incomplete.  Restating it for the Nth time is not going to get me to believe you (or anyone else) over my lying eyes.  Note that straight and level are not the same thing.

Comment: @FinncentPrice Consider creating a similar plot but with higher resolution (increasing the DPI) and have the line extend a longer distance. And if you run my code, does it not produce a straight and level line without any wiggles? If it does, then it shows that the line before was straight but not level.

Comment: @FinncentPrice I added a small edit to the end of my answer. The reason the documentation seems to show the arrows are in xkcd style is because they added a small curvature to each of the arrows with the keyword argument `connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.05"`. If you remove that and run their code, you'll see that all the lines are straight and level.

Comment: @jared Your edit is useful for other people finding this question, thank you.  However, I'm not really concerned with the lines in the documentation, but rather the black lines in the plots in my question.  They are unambiguously wiggling.  It is very easy for me to see in the plot with the red line.  What I could see if I changed the plot is irrelevant, the plot I've used here is something I actually want to plot (with straight lines) with a bunch of other elements removed.

Comment: @FinncentPrice I'm saying that if it is wiggling, then changing the parameters I show shouldn't affect that, yet my results are not wiggling. In the end, you can *believe* that they are wiggling, but your beliefs don't change the fact that they are *not* wiggling.

Comment: @FinncentPrice I have shown that by modifying your code, the results are straight and level, without any changes to the line type or style. I have yet to see your proof that the line is wiggling, since all you have said is that to you it *looks* to be wiggling. That is not proof, that is a single observation (and everyone in the comments disagrees with your observation, but you reject them without proof). I have nothing further to add on the matter.

Comment: I suggest [turning on XKCD styling](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xkcd.html) with the original plot to really get wiggly lines.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the line is straight, it is just angled. The reason for that is the vertical alignment of the text pulling the arrow up. If you add `va="center"` (you can also use the entire name, `"verticalalignment"`), the line will be straight.

As for the arrows not going all the way to the lines, that is because of two reasons.

1. There are arrow properties `shrinkA` and `shrinkB` that control the starting and ending offsets, which are set to 2 points by default (search for "shrinkA" in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html)). Setting `shrinkB=0` will result in the left arrow touching the line. As for the right arrow...
2. The arrowhead is displaced by the text since the starting coordinate specifies the (in this case) left edge of the text. To avoid this space, you can either fudge the coordinates to make the arrowhead end at the vertical line or create two annotations, one for the arrow without any text (just put the text as an empty string) and another that has just the text. (There may be another way that I'm not aware of.)

Here I make the change to the vertical alignment and both shrink values (although `shrinkA` won't bring the arrow to the line, it will at least get it closer).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6, 6))

p1 = 0.3
p2 = 0.7
y = 0.75
ax.axvline(p1, color="k", linestyle="solid")
ax.axvline(p2, color="k", linestyle="solid")

ax.hlines(y, p1, p2, "r", alpha=0.5) # proves the line is now horizontal

ax.annotate("blah",
            xy=(p1, 0.75),
            xytext=(p2, 0.75),
            va="center",
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<->", shrinkA=0, shrinkB=0)
            )

ax.set_ylim(0, 1.1)
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Edit: To be clear, the default style is not xkcd style. The reason they look that way in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/fancyarrow_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-fancyarrow-demo-py) is because they have added a little curve to each of the arrow paths with the `connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.05"` keyword argument. The documentation really shouldn't have done that since it doesn't show the default functionality and seems to imply that the arrows are normally curved.